# ES6 circular dependency. Implementing dependency hub

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, getter, circular-dependency

I found a lot of articles about circular dependencies and that it indicates the design/architecture flaws in the project. In most of the cases it can be fixed easily by slightly refactoring your classes.

In this example I'm trying to create a hub for dependencies. This is a library of classes that can be imported by different projects. The goal is to have getters in the main class that will return an instance of the dependency. This instance has to be a singleton and it's stored in the main class' dependencies that next time if someone calls a getter - it will return the same instance of that class.

Here is how code looks like:

```
// deps

import { DepA } from './dep-a';
import { DepB } from './dep-b';

const depsKey = '__MY_DEPS__';

class Deps {
  dependencies = {};

  get depA() {
    return this.getDependency('depA', DepA);
  }  
  
  get depB() {
    return this.getDependency('depB', DepB);
  }  

  bind(key, value) {
    this.dependencies[key] = value;
  }

  getDependency(key, serviceClass) {
    let service = this.dependencies[key];

    if (!service && !!serviceClass) {
      // if instance is not created yet, we instantiate the class and put instance in the dependencies
      service = new serviceClass();
      this.bind(key, service);
    }

    return service;
  }
}

export const deps = (() => {
  window[depsKey] = window[depsKey] || new Deps();

  return window[depsKey];
})();

// dep-a

import { deps } from './deps';

export class DepA {
  methodA() {
    console.log(deps.depB);
  }
}

// dep-b

import { deps } from './deps';

export class DepB {
  methodB() {
    console.log(deps.depA);
  }
}
```

As you can see - this creates a circular dependency problem, since class Deps uses classes DepA and DepB in its getters to create an instance of those classes if it doesn't exist. And classes DepA and DepB use an instance of Deps to retrieve each other via its getters.

I hope this explanation is not very cumbersome.

Can anybody suggest the changes I need to make to get rid of the circular dependency here but to keep an idea of accessing singletons via Deps class (deps instance)?

Comment: If `Deps` is a singleton, couldn't `DepA` import `Deps` and register itself? That would be my approach.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @loganfsmyth. How you'd access DepA from outside, or who'd trigger an instantiation of DepA?

Comment: Are you sure you need singleton instances? Many times you can get the same effect, but more optimally, with just modules and module-level constants holding any private state you need.

Comment: Why not just export your singletons and import that file where you need them? Then you don't need a clever manager or circulatirity.

Comment: @somethinghere That was the original approach until I got into a dilemma that in fact I'm not using a singletons, but 2 different instances - one in the library and the other one in the app. Let's say I export a singleton for DepA class and import that in DepB and in some other class in my app - those are 2 different instances at the end. Or I'm missing something here?

Comment: Yes, but can’t you just export both singletons from a file (import them, instantiate and then export) and only import the dependency you need from that file?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this will create an instance of every file I export from my library, which is not optimal. An instance has to be created on-demand.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by an instance of every file? I agree that singletons like this are pretty uncommon, or if I did have them, I'd instantiate then and export them from a central module.

Comment: Exported members are _not_ duplicated. That's the whole point of modules - one instance that can be shared by many. If they would instantiate their own instance every time they get used, that would be a bad idea. So any exported member only gets exported _once_ and shared by all modules that import it.

Comment: Notice that while your code contains circular dependencies, it does **not** create a circular dependency *problem* - the exports are not used synchronously anywhere before they are initialised. It just works.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Sorry, I wasn't clear - I meant it will create an instance of every class that I will export when I bootstrap the app. What I wanted is to instantiate only when some code calls a getter from the main class.

Comment: Then you can have the module export a function that instantiates the object the first time it is called and otherwise returns the existing one.

Comment: Right. That's what `getDependency` method does

Comment: The issue with the circular dependency is that you're trying to place both the logic of _what_ is a singleton in the same place, which you don't need to, and introduces cycles. Instead of importing both DepA and DepB in one file that is responsible for instantiating them, put that stuff in separate files and have the a-creation and b-creation logic manage their own singleton. There's no reason for there to be a `Deps` class at all when a JS module is already a singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be this:

#### a-singleton.js

```
import { DepA } from './dep-a'; 

let singleton;
export function getA() {
  if (!singleton) {
    singleton = new DepA();
  }
  return singleton;
}
```

#### b-singleton.js

```
import { DepB } from './dep-b'; 

let singleton;
export function getB() {
  if (!singleton) {
    singleton = new DepB();
  }
  return singleton;
}
```

then wherever you need these singletons, you can import the file and call the function to get the singleton.

Depending on what these classes do and how/when they reference eachother, you may also be able to directly do `export default new DepA()`, but depending on how they reference eachother, and how much they need to do at instantiation time, the lazy approach I've shown here can be better or necessary.

Comment: Ok, thanks @loganfsmyth. I get the idea. Will try to implement it.